# Not Able to Run GEM5 with RISC-V: "!seWorkload occurred: Couldn't find appropriate workload object"

Tags: python, c++, gcc, riscv, gem5

I am trying to run gem5 with RISC-V. I have the Linux 64-bits cross compiler ready and I have also installed and compiled gem5. I then tried to use the following tutorial to run gem5: https://canvas.kth.se/courses/24933/pages/tutorial-simulating-a-cpu-with-gem5

I wrote a simple Hello World C program and compiled it using the following command:

`riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -c hello.c -static -Wall -O0 -o hello`

But when I try to run gem5, I get the following error:

```
build/RISCV/sim/process.cc:137: fatal: fatal condition !seWorkload occurred: Couldn't find appropriate workload object.
```

I tried to come over this problem but I could not. I added print statements to the configuration file and realized that the error occurs in the line `m5.instantiate()` in the configuration file attached below. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? What is an seWorkload and why gem5 considers the object as not appropriate?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. For reference, this is the configuration python file I use for gem5:

```
import m5
from m5.objects import *
import sys

system = System()

system.clk_domain = SrcClockDomain()
system.clk_domain.clock = '1GHz'
system.clk_domain.voltage_domain = VoltageDomain()

system.mem_mode = 'timing'
system.mem_ranges = [AddrRange('512MB')]
system.cpu = TimingSimpleCPU()
system.membus = SystemXBar()
system.cpu.icache_port = system.membus.cpu_side_ports
system.cpu.dcache_port = system.membus.cpu_side_ports
system.mem_ctrl = MemCtrl()
system.mem_ctrl.dram = DDR3_1600_8x8()
system.mem_ctrl.dram.range = system.mem_ranges[0]
system.mem_ctrl.port = system.membus.mem_side_ports

# start a process
process = Process()

# read command line arguments for the path to the executable
process.cmd = [str(sys.argv[1])]

system.cpu.workload = process
system.cpu.createThreads()
root = Root(full_system = False, system = system)

m5.instantiate() # the error occurs from this line

print("Beginning simulation!")
exit_event = m5.simulate()
print('Exiting @ tick %i because %s' %(m5.curTick(), exit_event.getCause()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`m5.util.addToPath('../../')` is missing. This is used to add the common scripts to the path to your directory from where you are instantiating the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
system.workload = SEWorkload.init_compatible(binary)
```

I met the same problem and solved it by adding this line before creating the process. From gem5 documentation, the problem may be caused by version differences.

[image]